# Spring+jsp session

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi, I'm very much new to Spring.  My project deals with spring+hibernate+jsp.  I'm very much worrying about the task given to me

Task:

I want to store a jsp text box value in the session and then after steps I want to retrieve it in the spring controller to proceed database process... please help me.

Comment: FYI - storing data in the session can be dangerous.  I've had issues where my pages did not display correctly because former developers were relying on the session data which had expired.

Comment: Mr.Jessemon In my case i want to move up with 4 steps registration process like wizard how can we over come this

Answer (score 1):

In jsp:

```
 <c:set var="name" value="yourname" scope="session"  />
```

In spring

```
  ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)  
     RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
   HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
   session.getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: Avoid using scriptlets in JSP.

Comment: Mr.PSR i tried your suggestion it works like a charm but only thing is how can i pass the    <input id="stufirname" type="text" name="stufirname" value="" /> value to <c:set var="name" value="yourname" scope="session"  /> value

Comment: I tried to solve this problem but ends in vain    In jsp:-i wrote  <%
////////////// get the login information:
  String userName = "sudharsan";
 

////////////// and save it in the session:

  session.setAttribute("username", userName);
%> i can able acess the session value in spring mvc but when i pass the value dynamically as  String userName = request.getParameter("name"); i can able to get only NULL value in spring mvc..pls help me to over come this

Answer (score 1):

if you want a 4 steps registration process using a spring project, I would suggest you to take a look at Spring Web Flow. you can find samples [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples) tutorials [here](http://springinpractice.com/2008/05/05/build-a-shopping-cart-with-spring-web-flow-2-part-1/) and search on stackoverflow and the web. It is used to do exactly what you want.

Otherwise, you need to add the @SessionAttributes to your controller and declare @ModelAttributes. Here is an example:

```
    @SessionAttributes({"oneDto","secondDto", [...as many as you want...]})
    public class MyController {

        [...Declaration and init of forms and modelAttributes...]

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processFirstPage(
            @ModelAttribute("oneDto") OneDto infoFromFirstPage,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

                    [...Do whatever you need...]

            //return form success view
            return "secondPageView"; //uses secondDto

        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processSecondPage(
            @ModelAttribute("oneDto") OneDto infoFromFirstPage, @ModelAttribute("secondDto") SecondDto infoFromSecondPage
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

                    [...Do whatever you need...]

            //return form success view
            return "thirdPageView";

        }
    }
```

From the JSP Point of view, the dto is declared in the 'modelAttribute' of the form and all the fields are in path of inputs, selects, etc:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="oneDto" action="matchResquestMappingURL" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<form:input path="oneField"/> 
etc.
```

[full TLD description here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html)

You don't have to use multiple DTO, you can use the same one and add more info on each page.
When you're done with using your datas, call `status.setComplete();` to clean the session.

That's just a base for you to understand the concept but there are many other ways to deal with this. for example you can check this out [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/). (multiple page forms)

Comment: After much struggle i compled the task thanks friends for all your guidence...in personal view go with Tabbed form in case you are in the process of creating multi page form...pls have a look Twitter bootstrap it is much useful..